# Azure Application Gateway with App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

Requirement I have -

I want to do redirection like this. I have multiple App service that will be running and based on the url I want to do redirection to the proper one.

Something like this -

`test.com/v1 -> app service appv1.com
 test.com/v2 -> app service appv2.com
 test.com/v3 -> app service appv3.com`

Is azure application gateway the right choice for this considering it supports url mapping.

Though, I am unsure if application gateway for a app service will work? Does the public IP of the App service static ? Should that be used for configuration with the Application gateway

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to route traffic to different backend pools (including VMs and Azure App Services) via URL paths by using Path-Based Rules - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal.

This will allow you to use a "static" root domain (which you might want to purchase an SSL certificate for) and route traffic according to the path after the '/'.

Answer (score 1):

> Is azure application gateway the right choice for this considering it
>   supports url mapping?

I don't think so. Consider the pricing of Application Gateway. To have SLA support you need at least 2 medium instances. That is ~$51.10/month or let's say $100 per month for just the redirection. What kind of traffic you expect for this redirection?

Consider adding a another Web App to one of the existing App Services you have for for appv1.com, appv2.com, or appv3.com.

Another web app would have custom domain binding for test.com and redirect rules (I don't know if this is Windows or Linux web app).

Answer (score 0):

In the moment Application Gateway only supports multiple sites based on different hostnames / FQDNs. I would not know how to add multiple sites with different paths / routes.
[Also check out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-multisite-portal)